# the former and the latter

Tags: pronouns

Is there another pronoun following these ones? For example:

I have 3 brothers. The former; likes dancing, the latter; likes studying and the third one likes exercise.

Is it correct to use the pronoun "third" on speaking about more than 3 people at this kind of structures?

Comment: *Former* and *latter* normally refer to things you've written. I think you're looking for *first* and *last*, or *oldest* and *youngest* - these can refer to the individuals among the (unlisted) "3 brothers". Also, I think the semicolons should be removed from your example.

Comment: You wouldn't use "former" and "latter" in the given context. You _could_ use it if you had already listed the three brothers (e.g. " I have 3 brothers: Andy, Bob and Charlie."), but it would be unusual to use it when the number of items (brothers) is not **two**. If you did use it, then "latter" would refer to the last item in the list, not the second, so saying "third one" wouldn't make sense.

Comment: (I think the downvote makes no sense if unexplained.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the former and the latter when you are referring to two persons or things already mentioned.  If you are referring to more than two persons or things, you can use the first and the last as follows:

I have three brothers: John, Phil, and Joe.  The first likes dancing, the second likes studying, and the last (third) likes physical exercise.

Comment: In the particular case of referring to people (brothers etc.) I would use names. "I have 3 brothers: John likes dancing, Phil likes studying, and Joe likes to exercise" If you are telling someone about your family it would seem natural to use their names.

Comment: @JamesK, That's better.